# Passing multiple concatened commands to a exec statement fails

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, exec

I have a script (starter.sh) that simply contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec "$@"
```

The script is configured to exec the content of a certain environment variable (i.e. COMMAND)

If the environment variable contains a single command, it works:

```
 COMMAND='unzip myfile.zip'
```

But if I try to concatenate several commands (with `&&` or `;`) it fails:

```
COMMAND='unzip myfile.zip && cd /home'
```

with the error:

```
caution: filename not matched
```

The error is obviously raised by the unzip command that get confused by the && that somehow is no longer interpreted as concatenation.

The question is if there is any way whatsoever to pass a concatenated list of commands to an exec statement without modifying the exec call in the file "starter.sh"
The only option I have is to modify the content of the environment variable to a list of commands (not a path to a shell file that would be a obvious solution otherwise)

Comment: Where does your script `starter.sh` use environment variable `COMMAND`?

Comment: `exec` ends the current shell, and running multiple commands requires a shell. I don't fully understand your constraints, but would running a *new* shell with something like `sh -c 'unzip myfile.zip && cd /home'` work? (BTW, what's the point of running `cd` here, since it's just going to exit immediately afterward?)

Comment: @Cyrus, I don't really know, it's part of the kudu framework running I Azure Web Apps. Kudu let one customize deployments by using the environment variable COMMAND

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it was an interesting attempt, but with your suggested syntax I get an error "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string".
For clarity, I have set COMMAND=sh -c 'unzip -o node-app -d $DEPLOYMENT_TARGET && cd $DEPLOYMENT_TARGET && yarn bootstrap'
The error is:Syntax error:
Unterminated quoted string\\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh sh -c 'unzip -o node-app -d $DEPLOYMENT_TARGET &amp;&amp; cd $DEPLOYMENT_TARGET &amp;&amp; yarn bootstrap'"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe this Kudu/Azure setup in detail. That's crucial info. We haven't been able to give a good answer because it hinges on *precisely* how `COMMAND` is connected to `starter.sh`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, I intentionally omitted the Kudo environment since I constrained my question to how to run multiple commands stored in an environment variable and executed by exec. Does the Azure Kudu information help?

Comment: Yes, it does. Do you see that your question shows how `COMMAND` is set, but not how it is used? `starter.sh` doesn't use `$COMMAND`, so there are one or more steps missing between setting it and `starter.sh` being invoked. We can't answer this without knowing how `$COMMAND` is expanded...

Comment: ...e.g. is it done in a shell script as `$COMMAND`, or quoted as `"$COMMAND"`? Or is it done in a C program via some other mechanism? Are you able to change the code that uses `$COMMAND` or is it some third-party software you don't control?

Comment: It's standard third-party software that I don't control and cannot modify, that is why my focus is on what kind of syntax can I try to use with the environment variable COMMAND. I can't see where and how $COMMAND is passed to /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question with this information. Comments are ephemeral and could be deleted at any time.

Comment: It's looking like you're going to be out of luck, though. You'll probably have to put the complicated commands into a script of their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] file [redirection ...]
> Exec FILE, replacing this shell with the specified program.

That is, `exec` expects a file to execute. Then when you add more than one command the whole string is trying to be interpreted as a file name.

So if you want to pass something that's not a file name then don't use `exec`.

Comment: It accepts arguments: `exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]`